# Given the orthonormal ordered base pairs $ \hat s_1, \hat s_2$ of $V = R ^ 3 $ below, determine if $\hat s_1, \hat s_2 $ has the same orientation ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, determinant

Given the orthonormal ordered base pairs $ \hat s_1, \hat s_2$ of $V = R ^ 3 $ below, determine if $\hat s_1, \hat s_2 $ has the same orientation or has opposite orientations.

a-) $ \hat s_1$=($\vec e_1 =(0,0,1), \vec e_2 =(1,0,0), \vec e_3$ =(0,1,0))

$ \hat s_2$=( $\vec e'_1 =(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}), \vec e'_2 =(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}), \vec e'_3 =(\frac{1}{\sqrt 6},-\frac{2}{\sqrt 6},\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}))$

b-)$ \hat s_1$=($\vec e_1 =(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}), \vec e_2 =(\frac{1}{\sqrt 18},-\frac{4}{\sqrt 18},\frac{1}{\sqrt 18}), \vec e_3 =(\frac{3}{\sqrt 19},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 19},\frac{3}{\sqrt 19}))$

$ \hat s_2$= ( $\vec e'_1 =(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}), \vec e'_2 =(1,0,0), \vec e'_3 =(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}))$

================================================================

I did like that

a-)$(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, 0,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$= a(1,0,0) + b(1,0,0) + c(0,0,1)

a=$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, b=0, c=$-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

$(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$= d(1,0,0) + e(1,0,0) + f(0,0,1)

d=e=f= $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

$(\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}, -\frac{2}{\sqrt 6},\frac{1}{\sqrt 6})$= g(1,0,0) + h(1,0,0) + i(0,0,1)

g=$\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}, h=-\frac{2}{\sqrt 6}, i=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$

det $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\
                    d&e&f\\
                    g&h&i\\ \end{bmatrix}=1$

det = 1  same orientation

b-)

$(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$= a(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$) + b(1,0,0) + c(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,-$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$)

a=$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, b=$\frac{2}{3}$, c=-$\frac{1}{3\sqrt 2}$

$(\frac{1}{\sqrt 18}, -\frac{4}{\sqrt 18},\frac{1}{\sqrt 18})$= d(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$) + e(1,0,0) + f(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,-$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$)

d=$-\frac{1}{2}, e=\frac{1}{3\sqrt 2}, f=-\frac{5}{6}$

$(\frac{3}{\sqrt 19}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt 19},\frac{3}{\sqrt 19})$= g(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$) + h(1,0,0) + i(0,$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$,-$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$)

g=$\sqrt\frac{2}{19}, h= \frac{3}{\sqrt 19}, i=-2\sqrt\frac{2}{19}$

det $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\
                    d&e&f\\
                    g&h&i\\ \end{bmatrix}=\frac{\sqrt 38}{228}>0$ same orientation?

Comment: Define "orientation"?

Comment: The determinant of such a matrix determines whether the orientation of the basis is consistent with or opposite to the orientation of the standard basis.In the case a, it was a mistake by the teacher. There is a missing sign, so det = 1 so that they have the same orientation. In case b, I don't know if there was another error or if the det does not necessarily have to be +1 or -1. If det  different from 0 it is enough to determine the orientation. So in this case in b it would also have the same orientation becouse det >0.

Comment: There is also the possibility that I made a mistake in any part of the exercise.

Comment: So by orientation of a basis you mean whether it is right of left handed?

Comment: I don't think left and right matter. I think the question is whether the two bases "point" in the same direction.

Comment: Apologies if I'm being dumb, but how do we define which direction a set of basis vectors "point"? Given a basis $\mathcal{A}=\{\underline{a_1},...,\underline{a_n}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{\underline{b_1},...,\underline{b_n}\}$ are we concerned with the quantity $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\underline{a_k}} \mathbf{\cdot} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\underline{b_k}}$?

Comment: I am definitely not in a position to think that someone is stupid. The thing is that I never stopped to think about the definition of orientation that was used, and the teacher did not mention it. I think I ended up interpreting that where the vector "points" it doesn't matter (in this case) what matters is whether the 2 vectors "point" to the same side, that side in itself does not matter. In short, I don't know how to answer your question, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109209/discussion-between-k-defaoite-and-gabriel).